# Including a distance matrix in a CP schedulling problem

Tags: optimization, sequence, cplex, job-scheduling, constraint-programming

I want to try to add a distance matrix to a simple scheduling problem in CPLEX using CP however I cannot manage to get this in without an error in my new dvar sequence.

I am trying to include setup times between products 1,2 and 3 which depend on the sequence that the products are scheduled. The setup times for the different sequences are given in a distancematrix.I tried to define the distance matrix as a tuple triplet in the mod file and as a matrix in the dat file but both options do not work for me.

The new setup dvar sequence for this setup time is called setup, and should represent the sequence of every job J on a machine. However, I receive the error that 'the function noOverlap dvarsequence,[range][range] does not exists. I do not understand what I am doing wrong, since I defined the dvar seq and the matrix so in my understanding it should work

Could someone help me out here? Stuck with this problem for a while now.

Please find below the mod. and dat. files.

Thank you in advance!
mod.

```
using CP;

// Number of Machines (Packing + Manufacturing)
int nbMachines = ...;
range Machines = 1..nbMachines;

// Number of Jobs
int nbJobs = ...;
range Jobs = 1..nbJobs;

int duration[Jobs,Machines] = ...;

int release = ...;
int due     = ...;

int distanceMatrix[1..nbJobs][1..nbJobs] = ...;
 
dvar interval task[j in Jobs] in release..due;
dvar interval opttask[j in Jobs][m in Machines] optional size duration[j][m];

dvar sequence tool[m in Machines] in all(j in Jobs) opttask[j][m];
dvar sequence setup[j in Jobs] in all (m in Machines,j in Jobs)opttask[j][m];      

execute {
        cp.param.FailLimit = 5000;
}


// Minimize the total processing cost (24)

 dexpr int day = sum(j in Jobs, m in Machines) duration[j][m] * presenceOf(opttask[j][m]);
 minimize  day;
subject to {
  // Each job needs one unary resource of the alternative set s (28)
  forall(j in Jobs){
    alternative(task[j], all(m in Machines) opttask[j][m]);
     noOverlap(setup[j],distanceMatrix);
   }     
  // No overlap on machines
   forall(m in Machines){
     noOverlap(tool[m]);
   }     
  // forall(m in Machines,j in Jobs)
     
};

execute {
  writeln(task);
};
```

dat.

```
nbMachines = 2;

nbJobs = 3;

duration = [
        [5,1], 
        [3,4],
        [5,7]
            ];

release = 1;

due = 30;

distanceMatrix = [
1:[0,2,0],
2:[4,0,6],
3:[0,2,0]
]};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should turn the distance matrix into a tuple set.

See example from [How to with OPL ?](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-opl-alex-fleischer/)

TSP (Traveling Salesman Problem) in OPL with [scheduling](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/tspcpo.mod), with Constraint Programming, or with remove circuits and MTZ

```
using CP; 
int     n       = ...;
range   Cities  = 1..n;

int realCity[i in 1..n+1]=(i<=n)?i:1;



// Edges -- sparse set
tuple       edge        {int i; int j;}
setof(edge) Edges       = {<i,j> | ordered i,j in 1..n};
setof(edge) Edges2       = {<i,j> | i,j in 1..n+1};  // node n+1 is node 1

int         dist[Edges] = ...;
int         dist2[<i,j> in Edges2]=(realCity[i]==realCity[j])?0:
((realCity[i]<realCity[j])?dist[<realCity[i],realCity[j]>]:dist[<realCity[j],realCity[i]>]);


dvar interval itvs[1..n+1] size 1;


dvar sequence seq in all(i in 1..n+1) itvs[i]; 

execute
{

cp.param.TimeLimit=60;
var f = cp.factory;
  cp.setSearchPhases(f.searchPhase(seq));
}

tuple triplet { int c1; int c2; int d; };
{triplet} Dist = { 
    <i-1,j-1,dist2[<i ,j >]>
           |  i,j in 1..n+1};
           
           
minimize endOf(itvs[n+1]) - (n+1);           
subject to
{
    startOf(itvs[1])==0; // break sym
    noOverlap(seq,Dist,true);   // nooverlap with a distance matrix
    last(seq, itvs[n+1]); // last node
}
```

Comment: I tried to construct a tuple set as well, however I wondered if it was possible to construct a tuple triplet with Tasks is defined as a string { int loc1; int loc2; int value; }; 
{triplet} transitionTimes = { <i,j, ftoi(abs(i-j))> | i in Tasks, j in Tasks };                                   When Tasks is defined as a string Tasks = {"Ketchup", "Mayo","BBQ","KetchLight"};                            Or can tuple sets only be constructed with not string types?

Comment: The documentation says : An optional transition matrix M (in the form of a non-negative integer tuple set) can be passed to the noOverlap constraint meaning that if ai appears before aj in the sequence, then a minimal distance M[typei,typej] must be respected between the end of ai and the start of aj (typei and typej denote the types of ai and aj in the sequence).

Comment: Thanks Alex! I now see how I can set up my own tuple using only integers! Nevertheless, when I try to construct a tuple set for the transition matrix, replacing int loc1 and int loc2 with (string job1 and string job2), I get the error in the noOVerlap line: 
Argument type mismatch calling function noOverlap(dvar sequence,{tuple-type}):boolean with arguments dvar sequence, {Matrix}'.   Does this mean that I can only  use a tuple set which exists of non-negative integers for all parts of the tuple? It is still not completely clear to me.. Could you maybe confirm this?